# Rounded corners not working (in android emulator)

Tags: android, android-layout, rounded-corners

I'm having a problem with the rounded corners background shape in the emulator and I really can't figure it out.

The shape code is as follows:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="50dip" />
    <stroke 
        android:width="1dip" 
        android:color="#ccffffff" />
    <solid
        android:color="#cc111111" />
    <padding 
        android:left="3dip" android:top="3dip"
        android:right="3dip" android:bottom="3dip" />
</shape>
```

used in the following relative layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/loginboxlayout"
            android:layout_width="190dp" 
            android:layout_height="240dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded"
            android:padding="0dp" >
(...)

</RelativeLayout>
```

On the graphical layout, in eclipse, it displays correctly, but on the emulator it doesn't: [screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yqtw.jpg).

I'm using android 4.0.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put shape file in `res>layout` folder and then

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/loginboxlayout"
            android:layout_width="190dp" 
            android:layout_height="240dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@layout/rounded"
            android:padding="0dp" >
(...)

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: well... it was already on res/drawable but I had to put it in bin/res/drawable too and it worked. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

**Rect.xml---(Put this XML in drawable folder)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp" android:paddingTop="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp">
 <solid android:color="#eeeee0" android:paddingLeft="25dp" />
 <stroke android:width="0.8dp" android:color="#000000" />

<corners android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp" android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
    android:topRightRadius="15dp" />
```

**And add it where...watever control you want to round--**

```
android:background="@drawable/rect"
```

It will work definitely .

Comment: for sure not: it is missing the </shape> element :)

Answer (score 0):

Dont use dip as size formate. Use dp instead.

And Replace

```
<corners android:radius="50px" />
```

instead of

```
<corners android:radius="50dip" />
```

It will solve your issue.

Emjoy. :)